# Android view pager always load first cached item

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

i used ViewPager and Material TabLayout in my application .

i got problem with view pager . i used a ViewPager adapter class in 4 fragments and load Viewpager adapter with one Adapter Class . the problem is when i load each fragment view pager loads first time clicked fragment . looks like Viewpager caching the first loaded item . when i uninstall applicaiton and install again its ok for only first click and first load . after that viewpager always load first clicked item .

my adapter class code :

public class SubContentTabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

```
private Context myContext;
int totalTabs;
String Ttype;

public SubContentTabAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, int totalTabs , String type) {
    super(fm);
    myContext = context;
    this.totalTabs = totalTabs;
    this.Ttype = type;

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    String selected_tab = new String();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Fragment targetFragment = new Fragment();


    Log.e("TTYPE",Ttype);

         if (Ttype.equals("vid")){
        selected_tab = MovieFragment.tabLayout.getTabAt(position).getText().toString();
    }else if (Ttype.equals("audio")){
        selected_tab = AudioFragment.tabLayout.getTabAt(position).getText().toString();
    }else if (Ttype.equals("pdf")){
        selected_tab = BookFragment.tabLayout.getTabAt(position).getText().toString();
    }else if (Ttype.equals("img")){
        selected_tab = ImageFragment.tabLayout.getTabAt(position).getText().toString();

    }



    if (selected_tab.equals("بهترین\u200Cها")){

        bundle.putString("type", Ttype);
        targetFragment = new NewAndBestFragment();
        targetFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    }else if (selected_tab.equals("جدیدترین\u200Cها")){

        bundle.putString("type", Ttype);

        targetFragment = new NewAndBestFragment2();
        targetFragment.setArguments(bundle);


    }else if (selected_tab.equals("قالب")){

        bundle.putString("type", "ghaleb_tags");

        targetFragment = new ShowCategoryFragment();
        targetFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    }else if (selected_tab.equals("موضوع")){

        bundle.putString("type", "mozoo_tags");

        targetFragment = new ShowCategoryFragment();
        targetFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    }else if (selected_tab.equals("محتوا")){

        bundle.putString("type", "mohtava_tags");

        targetFragment = new ShowCategoryFragment();
        targetFragment.setArguments(bundle);


    }else if (selected_tab.equals("مخاطب")){

        bundle.putString("type", "mokhatab_tags");

        targetFragment = new ShowCategoryFragment();
        targetFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    }else if (selected_tab.equals("همه")){
        bundle.putString("type", Ttype);

        targetFragment = new ShowAllFragment();
        targetFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    }




    return targetFragment;


}
// this counts total number of tabs
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return totalTabs;
}
```

Comment: use `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`...

Comment: @NikhilSharma i tried this but its also have problem and looks like its caching only first selected item . its loaded same fragment always